# Finding algorithm to calculate maximum number of people in town simultaneously

Tags: algorithm

I would like a help in the following question of finding an algorithm to the following problem:

> Given a pair list (a<sub>1</sub>,b<sub>1</sub>),...,(a<sub>n</sub>,b<sub>n</sub>) , where a<sub>i</sub> is the entry date of a person i to the city and b<sub>i</sub> is the departure date of person i. Assume that you enter the city at the beginning of the day, and leave the city at the end of the day.
>
> For example, if a person entered the city on the 4th of the month, and left on the 12th of the same month, then he was in the city 9 days. Propose an algorithm as efficient as possible for the calculation of the maximum number of people who were in the city at the same time

My try:
Use two arrays, one for the entry and one array for the departure. Sort the arrays in ascending order. Iterate through the sorted arrays and for each iteration, if the current element in the entry array is smaller (or equal) to the current element in the departure array then increment a counter, otherwise we decrement the counter. After each iteration, update another variable for the maximum counts to be the maximum between the counter variable and the maximum counts variable.
Then print the maximum counts.

This is done in O(n log n). Is there a more efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure your algorithm is working correctly? If you split the pair in arrival and departure, you lose the connection when each person enters and leaves the city

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but (assuming you advance the current elements correctly) you are effectively merging the two sorted arrays on the fly. It would be more convenient and *very slightly* more efficient to sort all arrival and departure dates in one array together.

Comment: It depends on the range of the values for aₖ and bₖ. If they are integers in a relatively small range, you can put +1/-1 values in an array that spans that range. Then it becomes O() where  is the size of the range.

Comment: Build an array of events: for each person add two *events* to the array: time of arrival and time of departure; sort the array. Scan the array: for each arrival add 1, for departure subtract 1; compute maximum value while scanning. `O(n * long(n))` - since we have sorted the array. If dates of arrival / departure are not arbitrary but some kind of real dates (say, 2022 year) we can perform *radix* sort and get `O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an array(lets say count) of size 33 and initialize it all with 0s.
2. Now traverse through the pair list and for every pair `(ai, bi)`, do `count[ai]++` and `count[bi+1]--`
3. Now take a variable called `numberOfPeople` and perform following loop

   ```
   int numberOfPeople = 0, maxNumberOfPeople = 0;`

   for(int i=1;i<=31;++i){
        numberOfPeople += count[i];
        maxNumberOfPeople = max(numberOfPeople, maxNumberOfPeople);
    }
   ```

Inside the loop, for every `i`, `numberOfPeople` will represent the number of people present in the city on `ith` day. The time complexity of this solution is `O(n)`

This assumes that there are only max 31 days in a month and we are taking about a single month only. The solution can easily be modified if that is not the case

Answer (score 1):

Split each pair in two events: arrival and departure and put them into a collection.

```
List<(DateTime time, bool isArrival)> events = ...
```

Then sort the collection by `time`, e.g.

```
events.Sort((left, right) => left.time.CompareTo(right.time));
```

Finally, scan the collection: on arrival *add* `1`, on departure subtract `1` while computing maximum:

```
int result = 0;
int current = 0;

foreach (var event in events) 
  if (event.isArrival) { 
    count += 1;

    result = Math.Max(result, count);
  }
  else
    count -= 1;
```

It is *sorting procedure* that defines time complexity here. In *general case* we have typical `O(n * log(n))` time complexity;
however, if we have *real* dates, which are restrited (say, the all can be represented in `yyyy-MM-dd` format) we can perform *radix sort* and get `O(n)` time complexity.